# how to open and close a popup with same button / and hover issues

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I am desperately trying to create a button that when you click on a popup appears and when you click on it again the popup disappears.

In addition to that I am trying to make the text (of the button) stricktrhough when clicked on, remains stricktrhough when the popup is present and  back to its original state when you click on it again and the popup is gone...

But I'm sooo new coding and I'm having so much trouble. someone to help me?

Here is where I am...

*in index.html*

```
<button id="btnPopup" class="btnPopup">X</button>
<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
    <div id="popup" class="popup">
           <span id="btnClose" class="btnClose">&times;</span>
       <p>Text in popup 
       </p>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

*in style.css*

```
/* BOUTON */

.btnPopup{
   background-color:white;
   border: none;
   font-size: 60pt;
   font-size: max(5vw,35px);
   color:black;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
}

.overlay{
   position: fixed;
   left:5px;
   top:0px;
   font-size: 20pt;
   color: white;
   width:40%;
   height: 60%;
   display: none;
   z-index: 8;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .popup{
       width:20%;
    }
  }
.popup{

   margin:20% auto;
   width:90%;
   max-width: 800px;
   min-width: 300px;
   background-color: blue;
   padding: 1em;
}

.btnClose {
   float: right;
   cursor: pointer;
} 

/* BOUTON hover */


.btnPopup::after{
   content:'';
   display:block;
   width:0%;
   height: 10px;
   background:black;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 45%;
   -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
   -o-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.btnPopup:hover::after{
  width:100%;

}
```

*in script.js*

```
var btnPopup = document.getElementById('btnPopup');
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var btnClose = document.getElementById('btnClose');

btnPopup.addEventListener('click',openModal);
btnClose.addEventListener('click',closePopup)

function openModal(){
 overlay.style.display = 'block';

}

function closePopup(){
 overlay.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Your css is invalid. please update it.

Comment: You code is incomplete not just css, html have an error too and js is incomplete where's `btnPopup` reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically *add/remove* **classes** when popup is *opened/closed*. Hopefully it helps.

```js
$('#btnPopup').on('click', function(e)  {
  var btnPopup = document.getElementById('btnPopup');
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  var btnClose = document.getElementById('btnClose');
  
  if(!$(this).hasClass("opened")){
    //code for open & strikethrough
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
    $(this).addClass("opened strike");
  }else{
    //code for close & original state
    $(this).removeClass("opened strike");
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
  }  
});
```

```css
/* BOUTON */

.btnPopup{
   background-color:white;
   border: none;
   font-size: 60pt;
   font-size: max(5vw,35px);
   color:black;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
}

.overlay{
   font-size: 20pt;
   color: white;
   width:40%;
   height: 60%;
   display: none;
   z-index: 8;
}

.popup{
   background-color: blue;
   padding: 1em;
}

.btnClose {
   float: right;
   cursor: pointer;
} 

/* BOUTON hover */

.btnPopup:hover:{
  cursor:pointer;
} 

.strike{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnPopup" class="btnPopup">X</button>
<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
    <div id="popup" class="popup">
       <p>Text in popup 
       </p>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! That seems like a nice solution! Just a little precision (sorry I am new at this :S) In this case the code for the strikethrough has to be javascript as well or it could also be Css?

Comment: No problem. You can write it in your CSS. You can simply write your strikethrough for "strike" class. In the code above, it will add "strike" class when popup appears. I have added a code snippet to show how it works. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Okay just let me know when you encounter another problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use a simple `dataset` attribute with zero as the value you can do a simple little trick ( `1 - dataset.state` ) to toggle the state of that dataset attribute and thus control the visibility of the `popup`

I read comments about the CSS being invalid but have not focused on that - simply the javascript logic.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  this.dataset.state=1-this.dataset.state;
  this.nextElementSibling.style.display=Number(this.dataset.state)==1 ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
.btnPopup{
    background-color:white;
    border: none; 
    font-size: 60pt;
    font-size: max(5vw,35px);
    color:black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay{
    position: fixed;
    left:5px;
    top:25px;
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: white;
    width:40%;
    height: 60%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8;
}


.popup{

    margin:20% auto;
    width:90%;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 1em;
}


/* BOUTON hover */


.btnPopup::after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:0%;
    height: 10px;
    background:black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 45%;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s;
   transition: width 0.5s;
}

.btnPopup:hover::after{
   width:100%;

}
```

```html
<button class="btnPopup" data-state=0>X</button>
<div class="overlay">
   <div class="popup">     
      <p>Text in popup</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also simply omit the use of the `dataset` attribute altogether and use something like:

```
this.nextElementSibling.style.display=this.nextElementSibling.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block'
```

Comment: Wow cool thank you!!  I did not know this function (still have a lot to learn :))
Just a precision, why is it that to close the popup you can only click on the top part of the button, not the whole X is clikable?
The clickable zone of the button seems smaller to close the popup than to open it.

Comment: I think that is because of settings in your css